# Metal Shader pointer or local copy performance

Tags: performance, memory, kernel, gpu, metal

I have a metal kernel function that reads, processes and writes elements in a huge array of data, stored in **device** memory

`device Element *elements [[ buffer(0) ]],`

**I'm wondering what's better in terms of performance?** :

- Make a copy of the array element into local thread memory :

`Element element = elements[thread_id];`

- Or, use a pointer to that element :

`device Element *element = &elements[thread_id];`

Comment: There's a very good chance that it will optimize to the same code. If you're not going to change the element, then use `const Element` in all cases, which is just good practice but may improve the chances of optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm actually reading and writing the elements, I will reformulate my question

Comment: If you're modifying the elements (and want those modifications to be written to the buffer), then a local copy won't work, will it?

Comment: Well yes you can if you copy the element back into the array. I've seen weird implementations - maybe they make sense but I don't know - where the same buffer is taken twice as parameters to a kernel function, one version for reading and one for writing, then a local copy of an element is made out of the read buffer, processed, and then the result is copied at the element's place into the write buffer. I found that was a bit convoluted, hence the pointer question / that makes the implementation much clearer. Or maybe there's an optimization reason I don't see?